# disk free command: lots of repeated lines

Tags: disk-usage

On one of my Ubuntu machines, I accidentally typed `*.*` following the [disk free](https://linux.die.net/man/1/df) command:

```
df -h *.*
```

I got this output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
/dev/sda1       455G   26G  406G   7% /
```

What is the meaning of the output in this context?

Comment: What does `echo *.*` output?

Comment: Note: on Unix, *there are no extensions*. More exactly: file names can have any "." in them and it has no special meaning. If you write `*.*`, it simply means all file names containing a "`.`", and no more. The files *not* having a `.` in their file name, won't match this pattern. If you want to match all files in the current directory, write a "`*`".

Comment: Note#2: what the OS has to do with a file, is decided by its some first bytes and not by its extension, as on Windows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`*.*` would have expanded to a list of matching filenames in the current directory. Then from `man df` :

> df displays the amount of disk space available on the file system
>   containing each file name argument

If all the files in the argument list are on the same file system, you will get the same result multiple times.